# JQuery .slideToggle() strange behavior on some divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a little website for a friend, and i need to make a page where i have some links. Each link triggers a Jquery .slideToggle() to show a related div in the same page.

I've noticed using the latest version of Google Chrome that when the last page element triggers the .slideToggle() it has a strange animation: while the other divs are toggled as intended, the last seems to be toggled "slower" and less "fluid" than the others.

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
<a href="#" class="FAQ" data-link="faq1"><h2>+Experiences</h2></a>
<div class="info" id="faq1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent id tortor nisi. Morbi neque mauris, ornare sit amet varius id, malesuada a mauris. Nam libero neque, fringilla et dolor vitae, ornare gravida tellus. In eu felis lacus. Nunc placerat interdum diam, eget mollis orci luctus quis. Cras scelerisque accumsan purus, sed cursus urna faucibus eget. Aenean porttitor quam sed odio bibendum pretium. Nullam eget lobortis mauris, sit amet porttitor dolor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc rhoncus, urna eget mollis volutpat, purus ligula pretium turpis, in tincidunt purus nunc non neque. Integer mattis, urna non mattis porttitor, velit ligula tempus enim, bibendum bibendum sapien metus non enim. Aliquam tristique a purus eu blandit. Praesent eget dolor eget nulla malesuada efficitur vel at tortor. Integer eu egestas sapien, sed ornare quam. Cras libero ex, feugiat vitae lacinia vel, faucibus eget quam. </p>               
</div>
<a href="#" class="FAQ" data-link="faq2"><h2>+Awards and Prizes</h2></a>
<div id="faq2" class="info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent id tortor nisi. Morbi neque mauris, ornare sit amet varius id, malesuada a mauris. Nam libero neque, fringilla et dolor vitae, ornare gravida tellus. In eu felis lacus. Nunc placerat interdum diam, eget mollis orci luctus quis. Cras scelerisque accumsan purus, sed cursus urna faucibus eget. Aenean porttitor quam sed odio bibendum pretium. Nullam eget lobortis mauris, sit amet porttitor dolor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc rhoncus, urna eget mollis volutpat, purus ligula pretium turpis, in tincidunt purus nunc non neque. Integer mattis, urna non mattis porttitor, velit ligula tempus enim, bibendum bibendum sapien metus non enim. Aliquam tristique a purus eu blandit. Praesent eget dolor eget nulla malesuada efficitur vel at tortor. Integer eu egestas sapien, sed ornare quam. Cras libero ex, feugiat vitae lacinia vel, faucibus eget quam.</p> 
</div>
<a href="#" class="FAQ" data-link="faq3"><h2>+Publications</h2></a>
<div class="info" id="faq3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent id tortor nisi. Morbi neque mauris, ornare sit amet varius id, malesuada a mauris. Nam libero neque, fringilla et dolor vitae, ornare gravida tellus. In eu felis lacus. Nunc placerat interdum diam, eget mollis orci luctus quis. Cras scelerisque accumsan purus, sed cursus urna faucibus eget. Aenean porttitor quam sed odio bibendum pretium. Nullam eget lobortis mauris, sit amet porttitor dolor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc rhoncus, urna eget mollis volutpat, purus ligula pretium turpis, in tincidunt purus nunc non neque. Integer mattis, urna non mattis porttitor, velit ligula tempus enim, bibendum bibendum sapien metus non enim. Aliquam tristique a purus eu blandit. Praesent eget dolor eget nulla malesuada efficitur vel at tortor. Integer eu egestas sapien, sed ornare quam. Cras libero ex, feugiat vitae lacinia vel, faucibus eget quam. </p>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript/Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".info").hide();
});

$(".FAQ").click(function(){
var test="#"+$(this).attr('data-link');
$(test).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Here's the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wj02tbzu/10/).

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a value instead of "slow", for me that seems to fix it.
Also I recommand to put `return false` at the end of the function to prevent the view from going to the top of the page again.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see difference between all elements, the animation seems to works bad on each.

In this case the problem is the native `margin` of `p` and `margin-top` of `h2`. This seems to be related with `overflow` property gave to elements by jQuery `slideToggle()` function. A work around could be remove margin from those elements and giving `margin-bottom` to `.info` to keep the same original margin

```
p { margin: 0 }
h2 { margin-top: 0}
.info { margin-bottom: 19px }
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuptryou/).

Answer (score 0):

adding this to your css, fixes the jumping:

```
h2, p { margin-bottom: 0; }
```